# Why doesn't my specific implementation work for returning middle letter from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim is to return the middle letter of a string, or `" "` if the string's even. I'm failing to see why my code doesn't work. Any sort of clarification would be great, thanks!

```
def mid(ml):

    x=len(ml)
    y=x+1
    z=y/2
    if isinstance(z,int)==True:
        return (ml[z-1])
    else:
        return (" ")
        
print (mid("abc"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` doesn't return an `int`; even if the number it returns can be represented as one:

```
>>> 4 / 2
2.0  # A float
```

It would be better to explicitly check if the number is even or not:

```
# Read as: "If z is odd", or, "If division of z by 2 has a remainder of 1"
if z % 2 == 1:  
    return ml[z-1]
else:
    return " "
```

Comment: I wasn't aware "/" returns a float! Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior occurs, because the `/` operator returns a `float`. Although the smarter way to solve this would be the use of the [modulo operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html), if you want to stick to your code, could use the `is_integer()` method of `float` like this:

```
def mid(ml):

    x=len(ml)
    y=x+1
    z=y/2
    if z.is_integer():
        return (ml[int(z)-1])
    else:
        return (" ")
        
print (mid("abc"))
```

Better way to do it:

```
def mid(ml):
    return ml[len(ml)//2] if len(ml) % 2 else ""
```

Comment: Your first code block raises a TypeError because you are using a float as an index.

Comment: No it doesn't, this is the ```//``` operator, which returns an ```int```.

Comment: You are right about the TypeError, I was confused because this wasn't originally my code. I already corrected the ```len(ml) % 2``` before you commented though.

Comment: Yeah i didn't really know about the modulo operator, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

Following the answer from @Carcigenicate above you can try following code:

```py
def mid(ml):
    x=len(ml)
    y=x+1
    z=y/2
    return (ml[int(z-1)])
        
print (mid("abc"))
```

Comment: This fails for `mid("abcd")` where it should return `" "`

Comment: That doesn't correspond with the requirements